# Plot an expression which symbols name are stored in a vector

Tags: r

I have a character vector which contains Greek letters.

```
labNames <- c("rho x alpha", "z x rho", "beta x rho")
```

I want to see these labels on X axis, referring to the object labNames. The result must be as if I used expression(rho x alpha). Typing  expression(labNames[1]) is wrong, but I'm not able to figure out how to solve it. Please look at the following example:

```
plot(c(2,5,8), 1:3, axes=F, pch=19, xlab="", ylab="")
axis(2, 1:3, labels = c(expression(labNames[1]), expression(labNames[2]), expression(labNames[3])), las=2, tck = FALSE, lty = 0)
```

Comment: `expression(rho x alpha)` is not valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to format the expressions properly:

```
labNames <- c("rho x alpha", "z x rho", "beta x rho")
labNames <- gsub(' ', '~', labNames)
```

and then you can use `parse`

```
plot(c(2,5,8), 1:3, axes=F, pch=19, ann = FALSE)
axis(2, 1:3, labels = parse(text = labNames), las=2, tck = FALSE, lty = 0)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm immensely indebted to you.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion would be to just build a proper `expression` vector:

```
axis(2, 1:3, labels = expression(rho~bold(X)~alpha, 
                                 z~bold(X)~rho, 
                                 beta~bold(X)~rho), 
             las=2, tck = FALSE, lty = 0)
```

Or perhaps

```
 axis(2, 1:3, labels = expression(rho %*% alpha, z%*%rho, beta%*%rho), las=2, tck = FALSE, lty = 0)
```

[image]

Expressions in R need to have separators (ignoring spaces but most simply either `~` or `*`) between each token. Commas are used to separate items within the vector. If you wanted a mathematical "times" rather than a vector-cross between those tokens (quoted string, complete plotmath function, or name of greek letter), you would use either `%*%` or `%.%`. See ?plotmath for full range of acceptable separators

Comment: Actually, you are right - I want to obtain times instead of x. The following code works: `labNames <- c("rho %*% alpha", "z %*% rho", "beta %*% rho")
   plot(c(2,5,8), 1:3, axes=F, pch=19, ann = FALSE)
   axis(2, 1:3, labels = parse(text = labNames), las=2, tck = FALSE, lty = 0)`. But If I change into `labNames <- c("rho==1 %*% alpha==2", "z==2 %*% rho==2", "beta==1 %*% rho==3")` I get an error. Do you know how to fix it?